# No visible @interface declares the selector 'preferredStatusBarStyle:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The code below in an iOS project with a Deployment Target set to iOS 9 throws the following error:

> No visible @interface for 'MyMainHomeViewController' declares the selector 'preferredStatusBarStyle:'

```
@implementation MyMainHomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self preferredStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}

@end
```

Why is there no method called `preferredStatusBarStyle` in the ViewController?

Xcode compiler (clang-llvm) seems to be implying there should be, as seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there no method called preferredStatusBarStyle in the ViewController

Because there's no such method! It's a [read-only property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621416-preferredstatusbarstyle?language=objc), declared as:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIStatusBarStyle preferredStatusBarStyle;
```

So you can *get* that property, and you can *override* that property, but your code makes no sense, and the compiler rightly tells you so.